# Convert bitmap pixel to imageview pixel so they land on the same spot

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have an image view that loads a drawable image.  The imageview is set to wrap_content but since the original image is big then it fills the root layout.

I have pixels values of the Rect on the ORGINAL image that surrounds a face.
When I load this image to an imageview, I want to draw a rect around the face in the same fashion. **So basically I want to convert the bitmap pixels to imageview pixels.**

```
     After researching, I am using this code:
     // Where the rct is on original bitmap/image
     Rect rct= new Rect(200,500,300,700);

     //get Bitmap
     Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)ivPicture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

     //Calculate the scaling ratio
     double bmpWidthRatio = bmp.getWidth()/(double)ivPicture.getWidth();
     double bmpHeightRatio = bmp.getHeight()/(double)ivPicture.getHeight();

     //create new image view so I can draw the rect in the canvas
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
 ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     MyView v = new MyView(this);
     v.setLayoutParams(lp);


     v.rect.set((int)(rct.left/bmpWidthRatio),(int)( rct.top/bmpHeightRatio) ,
                 (int)(rct.right/bmpWidthRatio),(int)( rct.bottom/bmpHeightRatio));
```

And here is code for the custom imageview to use to draw on Rect

```
public class MyView extends View {
        public Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint bracketsPaint = new Paint();
            bracketsPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            bracketsPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            bracketsPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, bracketsPaint);
        }
    }
```

What I don't understand with this code? I mean it looks like the box is drawn at the right X value but somehow the Y value is messed up.

Isn't this how you would convert original bitmap pixel to imageview pixel for the same spot?

Thanks

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: your `MyView` does not draw any `Bitmap` inside its `onDraw` method, it only draws your rectangle: `canvas.drawRect` - also `super.onDraw(canvas);` is pointless here as `View#onDraw` method is an empty method, so where is the `Bitmap` drawn? on the separate `View` placed behind?

Comment: Yes i shouldve clarified. I am referring to 2 different image views. The one image view on the back that has the bitmap and the  custom view here that draw rectangle. I was able to figure it n out by doing matrix. Invert and use map points function

Comment: @pskink perhaps you can take a look at my recent question about getlocstionoacreen question. That is more specific and till now I am unable to figure it out

Comment: `mapPoints` is good if you have array of x/y points - for rect you can use `mapRect` method directly

Comment: but if you want to do that without any "overlay" view simply extend `BitmapDrawable` and override `draw(Canvas)` method - here you can directly draw your `200,500,300,700 Rect` without any `Matrix` mapping